# TypeError: JSON.stringify(...).then is not a function

Tags: json, reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap, webapi

I am new to react and having a problem. What I want to do is that I want to add departments to a table that I created through the web api created in visual studio. I want to add the department through the modal pop up. However, I am having an issue. Whenver, I click the add button it gives me this error.

```
TypeError: JSON.stringify(...).then is not a function
handleSubmit
D:/React/employee-app/src/components/AddDepModal.js:22
  19 |            'Content-Type':'application/json'
  20 | 
  21 |        },
> 22 |        body: JSON.stringify({
     | ^  23 |          DepartmentID:null,
  24 |          DepartmentName: event.target.DepartmentName.value
  25 |        })
View compiled
```

Here is my code where I call the 'POST' method

```
export class AddDepModal extends Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    }


    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        fetch('https://localhost:44363/api/Department',{
        
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'

        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          DepartmentID:null,
          DepartmentName: event.target.DepartmentName.value
        })
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then((result)=>
        {
          alert(result);
        },
        (error)=>{
          alert('Failed')
      
        }
        )

        }
        )
    }
```

Here is the part which I render on the screen(might not be required):

```
render(){
    return(
        <Modal
      {...this.props}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
          Add Department
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <div className="container">
            <Row>
                <Col sm={6}>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                      <Form.Group controlId="DepartmentName">
                          <Form.Label>Department Name</Form.Label>
                          <Form.Control
                              type = "text"
                              name="DepartmentName"
                              required
                              placeholder="Department Name"
                              />
                      </Form.Group>
                      <Form.Group>
                          <Button variant="primary" type ="submit">
                              Add Department
                          </Button>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Form>
                </Col>
                </Row>
        </div>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant= "danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
    );
}}

export default AddDepModal;
```

I am not understanding what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

You should use fetch like this

```
  fetch('https://localhost:44363/api/Department', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    DepartmentID: null,
    DepartmentName: event.target.DepartmentName.value
  }),
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

Comment: @sandeep pradhan did it work ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a `)`.
In your example you are calling `then(..)` function on the return value of `JSON.stringify(...)`

Comment: Hi where am I missing a ) could you tell me where I am missing a )

Comment: Yes got the error